# jquery selector select the second div with the classname X only

Tags: jquery

There are many divs in a page with the same classnames. How can I select only the second div with a specific classname, but nothing else, using jquery? 
Thank you!!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq/ or http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/. If you spend some time browsing the jQuery docs, simple questions like this should already be answered for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.eq` function like below,

```
$(selector).eq(1) //should return you the second element of the matching selector.
```

Or you can use `:eq()` selector like below,

```
$('selector:eq(1)') //should return you the second element of the matching selector.
```

Comment: Given that anything else is likely to be a rephrase of this answer, you might as well add in the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector approach too (if you don't mind?). =)

Comment: @user1818523 Sure np, don't forget to up vote/mark this is accepted if it solved your problem.